# why my while loop condition not working?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

This program asks for number irrespective of what character you enter. Then the problem is in the while loop.

Why my while loop condition not working ? checking temp isn't equal to NULL

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *ptr;
} nod;
nod *head = NULL;

void insert()
{
    int n;
    nod *temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter nnumber \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    temp->num = n;
    temp->ptr = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->ptr = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void display()
{
    nod* temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" --> %d", temp->num);
        temp = temp->ptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        insert();
        display();
        char ch;
        printf("\n enter more data ? (y/n)");
        scanf("\n %c", &ch);
    }
    while (ch != 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hiya, a properly formatted question is more welcome here :)

Comment: I see potential problem, but first edit your question so it looks readable.

Comment: Side note: all your function definition must be `...(void)`

Comment: Please provide a proper indentation. Code that is hardly readable does not attract lots of people to help

Comment: Not my best edit.. I thought the problem was with the `while` loop inside the function.  I am not sure where his problem is due to his poor question.

Comment: Remove the `char ch;` you declared *inside* the do-while loop in `main()`. Start with that. Unrelated, the `if (head == NULL)...else...` stuff is worthless for a front-pushing linked list. Just allocate your new node and populate its members, set it's `ptr` member to `head`, then `head` to the new node pointer value. No if-else should be needed in that function.

Comment: Instead of editing trash formatted questions like this, teach the OP how to edit it themselves. By fixing it for them, you are sending out the signal that posting complete trash is ok on SO. The correct way to deal with questions like this is to leave a comment telling the OP to fix the formatting, down vote, then remove the down vote once they have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are **re-declare** `char ch` inside the `loop`?

Remove `char ch` inside loop and fix your problem. Like,

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        insert();
        display();
        printf("enter more data ? (y/n)\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    }
    while (ch != 'n');    
    return 0;
}
```